# Java - Create random permutation without using temporary list

Tags: java

This is the last problem I could not solve:

---

1. You are given an array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`

Create a function that creates a random permutation without using a temporary list, in `Θ(n)` time.

---

Couldn't I use `Collections`.`shuffle` function to do this once I get the `int[]` array? I'm not sure what exactly the problem is asking for.  I could do a simple loop where I could randomize it using an iterative method and do a simple check but shuffle would be easier, no?

Comment: Not using a temp list means you should swap numbers in the input array to produce the output.

Comment: does the resultant number contain exactly n number of digits?

Comment: If I can swap numbers, shouldn't I use Shuffle? Or do you think they want me to actually do the shuffle hard-coded

Comment: @user3218114 That's all I've been given to the problem. That's all it says

Comment: @DanF Who is "they"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
index1 = 0
index2 = 0
loop: when index1 < array.length
         index2=random[index1,array.length]
         print[array[index2]
         swap[index1,index2]
         index1++
```

In Java:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
Random r = new Random();

while(x < array.length){

    y = x + r.nextInt(array.length-x);
    System.out.println(array[y]);

    int temp = array[x];
    array[x] = array[y];
    array[y] = temp;

    x++;
}
```